# "You can still avail of our discounted tickets for students." Is this sentence correct?

Tags: word-usage

> You can still avail of our discounted tickets for students.

This is a sentence from an English material I used in a lesson (https://eikaiwa.weblio.jp/information/travel-english/travel-english-buy-a-ticket-1).  Is this usage of "avail" correct?  I learnt at school that you say "you avail **yourself** of something".  Does this sentence still make sense without "yourself"?  Or is this just an error of the writer?

Comment: You're right. You avail **yourself** of something. I might avail **myself** of it also. Others might avail **themselves** of it. A reflexive pronoun is required.

Answer (score 2):

Again, you're right. *avail of our discounted tickets* is not English.